# Adding Cart functions for Amazon API

Tags: php, soap, amazon-web-services

I am trying to add cart functions to the AmazonECS class available at https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library

The main class of that project is https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library/blob/master/lib/AmazonECS.class.php

It currently supports ItemLookup and ItemSearch but it does not have CartCreate, CartClear, CartAdd, CartGet, CartModify.

Amazon's documentation about these API calls can be found on this page
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/CartCreate.html

Here's one of the things I have tried which hasn't worked.

```
/**
* execute CartCreate request
*
* @param string $asin, $associateTag
*
* @return array|object return type depends on setting
*
* @see returnType()
*/
public function cartCreate($asin, $associateTag)
{
$params = $this->buildRequestParams('CartCreate', array(
  array('Item.1.ASIN' => $asin, 'Item.1.Quantity' => 1),
  'AssociateTag' => $associateTag,
));

return $this->returnData($this->performSoapRequest("CartCreate", $params));
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The error message I get back from that call is

```
string(79) "Your request is missing required parameters. Required parameters include Items."
```

Comment: Can we check if those items can be delivered to Australia or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is still searching for an answer to this, I have this solution for you. The following is my cart function:

```
public function CartCreate($OfferListingId)
  {
    $params = $this->buildRequestParams('CartCreate', array(
        'Items' => array(
            'Item' => array(
              //You can also use 'ASIN' here
              'OfferListingId' => $OfferListingId,
              'Quantity' => 1,
      )
      )
    ));

    return $this->returnData(
      $this->performSoapRequest("CartCreate", $params)
    );
  }
```

The parameters you send should be constructed as an associated array.

Also, in case you get an error about not being able to add the item with ASIN to the cart, remember to add the country code to the Request, since the default is US and, for example, in my case I needed items from UK. This is how I do my Request:

```
$cart = $this->ecs->country('UK')->ResponseGroup('Cart')->CartCreate($OfferListingId);
```

Comment: Can we check if those items can be delivered to Australia or not?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I don't think your Item.1.ID should be part of another array. Try this instead:

```
$params = $this->buildRequestParams('CartCreate', array(
  'Item.1.ASIN' => $asin, 
  'Item.1.Quantity' => 1,
  'AssociateTag' => $associateTag,
));
```